Why is a Full Table Scan Used Instead of an Index Scan for My Query?
I have a query that performs a count operation on a table with a specific condition. I expected that using an index would be enough to speed up the query, but the output from EXPLAIN ANALYZE indicates a full table scan is performed even though there is an index on the column used in the condition.
Here is the query and the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM galleries
WHERE school_id = 3451;

The EXPLAIN ANALYZE output is:
Aggregate: count(0) (cost=29900.41 rows=21745) (actual time=63.052..63.052 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (galleries.school_id = 3451) (cost=27725.92 rows=21745) (actual time=50.530..63.026 rows=28 loops=1)
        -> Covering index scan on galleries using idx_school_id (cost=27725.92 rows=217449) (actual time=0.047..45.998 rows=197797 loops=1)


Despite the index scan being used, I am not seeing the performance improvement I expected. Why is this happening, and how can I improve the query performance?
Her is the table info

CREATE TABLE `galleries` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `school_id` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta` text,
  `file_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_processed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `original_name` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creator_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `video_size` double(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `available_resolutions` text,
  `upload_by` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` int DEFAULT '0',
  `parent_id` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_folder` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_deleted` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `captions` text,
  `drm_meta` text,
  `drm_video_id` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_video_id` (`video_id`),
  KEY `idx_school_id` (`school_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200396 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3



please include the output of show create table galleries

added please check the question@erik258

"200396" i can see you don't have very much data in that table.   But your indexes look good.  What version of Mysql are you running, something recent?  5.7 or 8.x?  Is your system memory or cpu constrained?

Test SELECT COUNT(school_id) AS total ...

@erik258 there are huge data in the table and 8.x but for that school id only 350 rows

What's the problem with Full Table Scans? They can be very efficient.

Ok, the issue was my school id was a varchar accidentally, when I changed it to be an int, it worked perfectly..

"school_id varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL," darn, it's right there ... I missed it :P.

You are doing school_id = 3451 and school_id is a character field.  Because one side of the = is numeric, a numeric comparison will be done, implicitly casting school_id to a number.  So it can't simply look up the '3451' entries in the index, it has to scan the whole index doing the cast on each value, so that values like ' 3451' or '3451.0' or '003451' or '3451 abc' will be included. Though it can still use the index to find all the possible values of school_id, rather than reading the actual table data, this will only provide a little improvement.
So if school_id is meant to only store ints, change it to an int type; otherwise do a string comparison:
school_id = '3451'

